# What happens when we define a bean inside the test folder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have defined a class with annotation @Configuration and some bean methods in it. This class is inside the test folder. So when I run the application will these beans be loaded by SpringBoot?

Comment: they will be loaded in [test](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config) classpath scope.

Comment: It wont affect your normal spring boot run.